# How to sort an array of date and list in ascending order in html table.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, date

I have an array with dates and i want to sort that array in ascending order and display it in html table. How could I do that in javascript.

This is my array

```
  <script>
     var dateArray =['20.10.2008','10.05.2008','12.03.2008','23.04.2010','21.05.2010','05.03.2009','09.12.2009']
 </script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please add what you have tried with sorting.

Answer (score 1):

```
var dateArray =['20.10.2008','10.05.2008','12.03.2008','23.04.2010','21.05.2010','05.03.2009','09.12.2009']

function sortDate(a, b){
        function toYYYYMMDD(date){
            var split = date.split(".");
            return parseInt(split[2] + split[1] + split[0]);
        }
        return toYYYYMMDD(a) - toYYYYMMDD(b);
    }

dateArray.sort(sortDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this,

```
var dateArray = ['20.10.2008', '10.05.2008', '12.03.2008', '23.04.2010', '21.05.2010', '05.03.2009', '09.12.2009'];
list = dateArray
  .map(
    function(val, idx) {
      var date = '21/01/2015';
      var d = new Date(val.split(".").reverse().join("-"));
      var dd = d.getDate();
      var mm = d.getMonth() + 1;
      var yy = d.getFullYear();
      mm = mm < 10 ? "0" + mm : mm;
      dd = dd < 10 ? "0" + dd : dd;
      return new Date(yy + " " + mm + " " + dd + ' 00:00:00');
    })
  .sort();

console.log(list);
```

This is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rfGv8/97/) link.

Comment: Thanks buddy.. :)

Comment: Welcome !! If my answer solved your problem, you can accept as answer !